# Laravel where with Bcrypt

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code:

```
$user = User::where([
                        ['email', '=', $request->email],
                        ['password', '=', bcrypt($request->password)],
                    ])->first();

    if(count($user) > 0) {
        return response()->json(['access_token' => $user->api_token, 'code' => '202'], 202);
    }
    else
    {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Please provide a valid email or password', 'code' => '200'], 200);
    }
```

But the problem is that it returns that the user does not exist because the password with bcrypt does not match. How can I make that the password that I am inserting and the database match?

Thanks

Comment: Use the auth stuff already given in the included modules, don't auth yourself.

Comment: How? can you show me?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication

Comment: But what about if I need to get a user? dont login just get a user how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question: User object based on username and Password without login.

Approach:

Step 1: Retrieve User based on email.

```
$user = User::where('email','=', $request->email);
```

Step 2: Check password is matching or not?

```
$isValidUser = false;
//If there is no user associated with email address.
if($user != null){
    $isValidUser = Hash::check($request->password, $user->getAuthPassword()); //returns true/false
}

if($isValidUser) {
    return response()->json(['access_token' => $user->api_token, 'code' => '202'], 202);
}
else
{
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Please provide a valid email or password', 'code' => '200'], 200);
}
```